# Copying files in a distributed system so that all servers have a copy of all files

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, concurrency, synchronization

Full disclaimer: This is an interview question:

There are M-machines. We need to copy data-sets from among these M machines to each other so that each server has a copy of all the data-sets. What is the most optimal algorithm to do this?

I know I can solve this problem in O(MN) (where N is the average number of data-sets on each machine) by iterating through each server. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Do you mean a sequential or parallel algorithm?

Comment: I think Arnold is just looking for a solution with a better time complexity - because of the interviews actually care only about that.

Answer (score 0):

What about a self-replication system?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replication#A_self-reproducing_computer_program

E.g.; If you have M=100 machines, for each data set you will have:

```
1tic: 1machine with the data
2tic: 2machines with the data
3tic: 4machines with the data
4tic: 8machines with the data
5tic: 16machines with the data
6tic: 32machines with the data
7tic: 64machines with the data
8tic: 64machines with the data
9tic: 100+machines with the data
```

I think this is less complex than O(MN)